# Graphing multivariable functions

Tags: calculator

Is it possible to graph out a multivariable function (3 variables at max) on a graphing calculator? If yes, how? My instrument is the TI83.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can have maps from $\mathbb R^1$ to $\mathbb R^2$; viceversa, and from $\mathbb R^1$ to $\mathbb R^1$. The graph of a function $f(x): X \rightarrow Y $ is the set {$(x,y): y=f(x)$} for some $x$, which is a subset of the Cartesian product $X \times Y$ . Then you need $X \times Y$ to be of dimension $3$ or lower, or you would need $4$ dimensions to do the graphing.

Comment: Hmm... ok but which button must I press in order for this to work? I am new to calculators (haha! My school didn't allow calculators: We used logarithm tables)

Comment: @Artemisia: Sorry, are you asking a question?

Comment: Oh never mind :) I got it :) Thanks :)